# about the archetypes listed by maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am following a [maven tutorial](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-creating-simple-weather.html) to create a simple maven project.

The tutorial says after I run the following command:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.custom \
      -DartifactId=simple-weather \
      -Dpackage=org.sonatype.mavenbook \
      -Dversion=1.0
```

I should be able to see a list of archetype, then I should choose this one :

```
16: internal -> maven-archetype-quickstart ()
```

But the listed archetypes in my terminal are all **remote** archetype, there is no **internal** one. Besides, I don't see the `maven-archetype-quickstart ()` . Why?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial example seems to be a bit outdated.

The [`archetypeCatalog` parameter description](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeCatalog) says:

> Since 2.0-alpha-5, default value is no longer internal,local but remote,local.

So use `-DarchetypeCatalog=internal,local` to get list of internal archetypes.